# EJB + Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, ejb

Sorry if the question has already posted, I want to know if GAE support EJB injection, I read the documentation but nothing about EJB or a hint to make it.

If someone has already experiment this combination, please tell me.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely not: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

Comment: Thank you for the good link, I found this link on many website site but each time tried to access it I had a 404 not found.